# Can anyone tell me why my image is not showing up on my rss feed?

Tags: image, rss

here is how it is created. Everything works except the image

```
 foreach (var blog in blogs)
        {
            xtwFeed.WriteStartElement("item");
            xtwFeed.WriteElementString("title", blog.Title + " by " + blog.Name);
            xtwFeed.WriteElementString("link",blog.BlogURL);
            xtwFeed.WriteElementString("description", blog.OutputMessage);
            //if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(blog.PictureURL))
            //{
                xtwFeed.WriteStartElement("image");
                xtwFeed.WriteElementString("url", blog.PictureURL);
                xtwFeed.WriteElementString("title", "image");
                xtwFeed.WriteElementString("link", blog.BlogURL);
                xtwFeed.WriteElementString("width", "144");
                xtwFeed.WriteElementString("height", "250");
                xtwFeed.WriteEndElement();
           // }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RSS 2.0 a channel can have an image, but items cannot. If you want to put an image in an item you have to make your description HTML and use an img tag.

Personally, I don't like HTML in item descriptions, but that's just me, I prefer plain text.